# How to restrict auto generated inheritance in System.Windows.Window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance

I am having WPF form which is inherited with `FormBase.cs` which is of type `Window`. Now I change normal forms inheritance with this created `FormBase.cs` base class. But now problem is every time partial class which is inherited with `FormBase.cs` automatically change to default inheritance which is `Windows` in every change in form. And I found

> > Partial declarations of 'Wpf_Fomrs.MainWindow' must not specify different base

this error while compiling code.

Code:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("")]
public class FormBase : Window, IFormBase // Base class
{
}

[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Form")]
public partial class MainWindow : FormBase // Created normal form
{
}

//Auto generated partial class which again inherited with `Window` class
public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window, System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector {
}

// I want this result every time.
public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector {
}
```

While using Win Forms I dont find such problem.
What is problem with code generation logic in WPF forms?

**EDIT**

XAML of `MainWindow` looks like

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf_Forms.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Form1" Height="350" Width="525" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"  xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Foundation.ControlsWpf;assembly=Foundation" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Topmost="True" WindowState="Maximized">
```

Comment: Could you please post the first few rows (header) of the MainWindow.xaml file?

Comment: @Herdo Added few lines of XAML of `MainWindow` in EDIT section.

Comment: Please don't call a WPF `Window` a "Form". That's an insult to my values and beliefs.

Comment: BTW I have no idea what you're trying to do, but your approach is wrong. You don't "inherit" from anything in WPF, nor implement interfaces on UI classes. Maybe if you could edit your question and explain what are you really trying to do we could tell you what's the correct way to do it in WPF.